# linux bash scripting with input at start of script

Tags: linux, bash, calculator

I'm trying to write a script that will take two numbers from the time of running the script. The script is called compute. I need it to take 2 inputs when I run the script, it would then output the result

Like this:

```
compute 3 + 1
3 + 1 = 4
```

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the arguments of a Bash script using `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc, where the number after the $ is the number of the argument. This means that if your script is called `compute`, then you could retrieve your "3 + 1" from `./compute 3 + 1` as the first three arguments using this syntax:

`$1` would be `3`, `$2` would be `+`, and `$3` would be `1`.

The fastest way to implement what you want would be to simply piggyback on the Bash tool that already does this: [expr](http://ss64.com/bash/expr.html). However, I'm assuming this is for a school assignment, so the objective is probably to roll your own; read up on [math](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1852886) [in](http://www.sal.ksu.edu/faculty/tim/unix_sg/bash/math.html) [Bash](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) [scripts](https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/).

Comment: If that's all the info you needed, be sure to click that checkmark to accept the answer. ;)

Comment: Next question, how do I make an if or case statement to check what operator is entered?

Comment: It's a little ugly, but it works: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html

I'd recommend using tldp.org for any more questions you've got-- it taught me nearly everything I needed to know when I was learning Bash.

Comment: I'd heartily recommend *against* using `tldp.org`. I'd focus on wiki.bash-hackers.org and wooledge.org. TLDP has notorious syntax errors and inconsistent practices. The other two are carefully curated.